# System slows down until I move the mouse

Tags: hardware, mouse

i installed a bunch of time many linux distro and never got this "bug".
It's kind of weird, the system run really fine , but when there is operation like update manager or download via any browser , etc. It goes well until a moment (never the same delay) and radically slow down or even stop , the pc doesn't freeze but the operation is paused , and when i touch the touchpad it continue .

i suspected hard drive issue , so i changed it , a bios issue , except AHCI i can't modify anything..., also suspected that ACPI stop the drive so i unchecked the box but still the same bug.

if anyone has already got this... it's not a deadly bug but a big annoyance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sounds like a bug with something related to timer interrupts.  Basically, the kernel is waiting for an interrupt to give the next process a short slice of time to run, but the timer interrupt signal never fires.  And moving the mouse happens to fire an interrupt too, so that's why the kernel starts scheduling time for all applications again then.

I suggest you file a bug report against the kernel on Launchpad.  The best way to do that on Ubuntu is by running the following command:

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

That will collect info about your system (things like kernel version & hardware info), send it to Launchpad, and then open a browser to file a bug report.  If you don't have a Launchpad account yet, you'll be asked to create one.  Make sure to explain well what your problem is, and answer if more info is asked.

Comment: nice idea, didn't think about it. if i get something i'll post it here ,thanks

Comment: What you can try first is to add `noapic` to the kernel boot parameters.  If you have grub2, you can do that by changing the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""` in `/etc/default/grub` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="noapic"`.

Comment: And don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` after editing the `/etc/default/grub`.